# Python3 how to identify the version HTTP used by server

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to work out what version a HTTP server is running.

I have seen previous posts about using requests, but requests does not seem to support version2, iy always outputs 11 for HTTP2

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://104.71.136.252/", timeout=60, verify=False)
>>> response.raw.version
10
>>> response = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com", timeout=60, verify=False)
>>> response.raw.version
11
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with standard requests, it is not supported yet. But you can take a look to https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper-h2 for such support

They offer HTTP2 solution for python coders